# I want know why getStaticProps don't work , and I know should return props but in this matter the getStaticProps is not working with fetch or not

Tags: next.js

can any one explain why getStaticPros don't work with me in Nextjs 13.4

```
import react from 'react';
import { NextPage } from "next";
function page()  {
    return (
        <div>Hello</div>
    );
}
export default page;

export async function getStaticProps () {
    console.log("getStaticPros");
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `app` directory?

Comment: I have do it with new method there function called "use" can Fetch data from api. maybe old method stopped in 13.4.4

Comment: Yes is Right , thank you Youssouf Oumar